# Apache and symbolic link in /var/www/html

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-httpd

I'm trying to create a symbolic link to */home/user/www* from */var/www/html*
so I can access the directory in my home folder from the URL: http://localhost/www/

I did: `ln -s /home/user/www /var/www/html` but when i access the URL above, the server returns *403 Forbidden*.

The directory */home/user/www* has permissions 775.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

Set permissions for `/home/user` to 711 and see if that helps any. Keep in mind... localhost/www won't exist unless you have a folder called `www` inside of the DocumentRoot.

Also, you're better off using `~/public_html` over symlinking `/var/www/html` to something in your home directory. Bad practice/juju.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean, `~/public_html` isn't that useful unless you have multiple users.

Answer (score 3):

1. Check `/home/user/www` and `/var/www/html` owners

Apache user\group must have access to `/home`, `/home/user` and `/home/user/www` paths

2. Check Apache configuration:

look for `FollowSymLinks` option

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    ...
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```